# How to upgrade libpq.dll to the latest version on Windows 10 64-bit?

Tags: postgresql, authentication, windows-10, libpq

I installed PostgreSQL 13.3 which supports **SCRAM authentication**. Now, when I try to connect to PostgreSQL, I get an error that SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above.

How do I upgrade `libpq.dll` to the latest version on Windows 10 64-bit? *Steps, please*. My Windows 10 is up to date with all updates.

PS: I know I could change the authentication method to md5, but I would like to use SCRAM.

Comment: The DLL is included in the Windows binaries [available from EDB](https://www.enterprisedb.com/download-postgresql-binaries). If you installed PostgreSQL 13.1 locally (why not 13.3?) you already have that DLL

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you! I fixed the problem by copying the libpq.dll fole from the PostgreSQL bin folder to the DBConvert Studio installation folder. The issue was that the DBConvert Studio used an old version of libpq.dll.

Comment: @Ludwig Wittgenstein  Ok, but Db Convert Studio (ver. 17.5) crashes on start when its libpq is replaced.

Comment: @fragg Hi! It won't crash if we use the compatible architecture, 64-bit driver for the 64-bit app and 32-bit driver for the 32-bit app. SCRAM authentication is supported by default in the latest version anyway.

Comment: @Ludwig Wittgenstein Thanks for the reply. Youre right, driver was 64-bit while Studio was 32-bit. Ive installed the newest version (X64), everything works.